# Is there a way to open a new window (applicable for onload=) in a existing window?

Tags: javascript

So OK, the following definitely works:

```
w=window.open(url);
w.onload=function (){};
```

But then, when I want to open a second new window (where the first new window is already processed by the function(){},i.e. becomes garbage to be collected) replacing the first new window, I tried the following which utterly fails:

```
w.location.href=url;
w.onload=function (){};
```

I am just wondering is there a solution to this? Since onload does have the power over a child window, it should in someway have the power over a child-window-replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, you can load to a specific window using the reference name.

For example, if you opened a window with:

```
 var w = window.open(url,"window1");
```

You can load a url to that same window by referencing the name - the second parameter. example:

```
 window.open(url,"window1");
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/JpXnc/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am just (still) wondering why I am still not able to use .onload starting from the second window...

Comment: Checdk out these two links, for that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372022/waiting-for-child-window-loading-to-complete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132537/how-can-i-check-to-see-if-a-child-browser-window-has-finished-loading